# Usefulness of Picard-Lindelöf's Existence and Uniqueness theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, intuition, 3d, lipschitz-functions

I have just been introduced to the Uniqueness and Existence theorems for first order differential equations. I can apply their methods and solve the required exercises but I am still left with a lot of basic questions.

For the purposes of this post I will focus only on Picard-Lindelöf' Theorem and it will be referred as *(A)*.

**Here is what I believe I have understood:**

•   (A) is used to determine if there exists a solution for a differential equation of a specific form ($dy/dx = f(x,y)$)

•   (A) is used to determine whether solutions of that differential equation in a specific domain are unique (ie they do not intersect)

**Here is what I am not sure I have understood:**

•   In order to apply the method of (A) for finding the general solution for the ODE, in a certain domain, an analytical solution has to first be accomplished so as to find a function that passes through the set of initial coordinates.

•   The result of this method is the result of the analytical solution

**Things I am certain I have not understood:**

•   When using the method of (A) it requires us to find a function that passes through the initial coordinates. Can this function be any function we want or do there have to be any other conditions than it being continuous? I understand it would help to be some function for which the convergence of said series would be easier to compute. I am asking strictly for limitations on choices, that otherwise would break the theorem.

•   Why if two solutions intersect does it imply that $\partial f / \partial y$ is not continuous? My question is about intuition, I am trying to understand it graphically in the 3-axis plot of $x , y , dy/dx$

Any and all help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT 1:
As per the comments I will now make clear what I mean by "method of (A)"

In the book I am studying from, after the theorem a mathod for determining the general solution, aparently based on said was introduced, namely:

$$y_n(x) = η + \int_ξ^xf(t,y_n-1(t))dt \qquad,where \; y_0(ξ) = η$$

Part of my question was about finding $y_0(x)$. I the book the differential equation is first solved analytically and then the general solution obtained, is used as $y_0(x)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking. The theorem in question is generally proved via Banach Fixed Point theorem, which in turn guarantees that the solution is locally unique. At no point is an actual analytic solution explicitly constructed. It's just abstract nonsense of applying fixed-point iteration. If two solutions intersect and aren't locally equal to each other, then something in the assumptions of the theorem need to be violated, for example $f$ being Lipchitz in $y$.

Comment: What you are sure you understand seems correct to me. For the second part, I don't think you "apply" (A) to find a solution. It is more a theoretical result about existence, it rarely helps you to "find" the solution. And the solution does not have to be "analytic", or expressible by simple formulas. For the third part, $y$ can be any function that has derivative. The last part about intuition is slightly less trivial, so I omit it in this comment.

Comment: @AlexR. I edited my question a bit, I hope it helps clear up what I am asking

Comment: @PeterFranek Do you have any suggestion as to where I can find information on my last question? About continuity of the partial derivative and intersection of ode solutions.

Comment: @Stamatis Not a full answer, but it may be worth to look at counter-examples where uniqueness fails. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Example_of_non-uniqueness If you want a solution $y=0$ and also another solution where $y=0$ for $t\geq 0$ and $y<0$ for $t<0$, then somehow you want that for $y<0$, $y'$ is quite "large" so that you are able to push the solution to $0$ in finite time. That is, $y'$ still needs to go to $0$ for $y \to 0$, but it has to go to zero very slow.

Comment: @PeterFranek thanks for the tip, I will look more into it